# How to bypass Cloudflare ddos protection scrape the website (python)

Tags: python, web-scraping

i want to scrape this website with python

https://animepahe.org/api?m=release&id=167&l=30&sort=episode_asc&page=1
but this site is protected by cloudflare

```
Checking your browser before accessing website.com.

This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.

Please allow up to 5 seconds...
```

does anyone know how to bypass it

Comment: By using a real browser, via e.g. https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python , I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
import cloudscraper
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
url = 'https://animepahe.org/api?m=release&id=167&l=30&sort=episode_asc&page=1'
r = scraper.get(url)
print(r.text)
```

This will handle Cloudflare protection and return the html for that page. You can install cloudscraper with `pip install cloudscraper`.